# Doctrine2 error "Expected known function, got 'COUNT'" when in order by clause

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I'm using doctrine2

I try to get the number of "Events" ordered by number of tickets sold

```
$manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$builder = $manager->createQueryBuilder();

return $builder
    ->select('e')
    ->from('AppBundle:Event', 'e')
    ->leftJoin('e.tickets', 't')
    ->orderBy('COUNT(t)')
    ->groupBy('e.id')
    ->setMaxResults(10)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
;
```

This produce the error

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 80: Error: Expected known function, got 'COUNT'

With the following DQL produce

> QueryException: SELECT e FROM AppBundle:Event e LEFT JOIN e.tickets t GROUP BY e.id ORDER BY COUNT(t.id) ASC

However if I put the `COUNT` in the `SELECT` part, it does work correctly (but then I have to do additional treatment to remove the unwanted field of the SELECT)

```
return $builder
    ->select('e')
    ->from('AppBundle:Event', 'e')
    ->addSelect('COUNT(t) AS nbrTicketsSold')
    ->leftJoin('e.t', 't')
    ->orderBy('nbrTicketsSold')
    ->groupBy('e.id')
    ->setMaxResults(10)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
;
```

Is using `COUNT` in an `ORDER BY` clause a known limitation of DQL ?

Comment: Just add `AS HIDDEN` to your last code (eg. `->addSelect('COUNT(t) AS HIDDEN nbrTicketsSold')`).

Comment: thanks, adding the AS HIDDEN permits indeed to have an array of Events as a result, and it seems "stackoverflow.com/questions/24765826" that actually putting a function in order by is a limitation, and one should use the solution you propose, if you can find the reference in the doc, it will make an acceptable answer for me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [EBNF](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#ebnf) in the doctrine docs actually state what's possible in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
OrderByClause       ::= "ORDER" "BY" OrderByItem {"," OrderByItem}*
OrderByItem ::= (SimpleArithmeticExpression | SingleValuedPathExpression | ScalarExpression | ResultVariable | FunctionDeclaration) ["ASC" | "DESC"]
```

With `FunctionDeclaration` containing these functions:

FunctionsReturningNumerics:
`LENGTH`
`LOCATE`
`ABS`
`SQRT`
`MOD`
`SIZE`
`DATE_DIFF`
`BIT_AND`
`BIT_OR`

FunctionsReturningDateTime:
`CURRENT_DATE`
`CURRENT_TIME`
`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`
`DATE_ADD`
`DATE_SUB`

FunctionsReturningStrings:
`CONCAT`
`SUBSTRING`
`TRIM`
`LOWER`
`UPPER`
`IDENTITY`

`COUNT` is part of the `AggregateExpression` group ([Link](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#aggregate-expressions)), those are not allowed in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Furthermore, the docs actually have an example further up using `AS HIDDEN` to order by count:

> Retrieve user entities with Arithmetic Expression in ORDER clause,
>   using the HIDDEN keyword:
>
> ```
> $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u, u.posts_count + u.likes_count AS HIDDEN score FROM CmsUser u ORDER BY score');
> $users = $query->getResult(); // array of User objects
> ```

Comment: thanks for the detailled answers, exactly what i was looking for